# What is wrong with this for loop? Compile fails on End If

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to scan 50 rows under this value "01/05/2022" when it is met in the predefined range.
Once it has found that value start the scan and stop scanning (with an Exit For) once the "TOTALE ORE" value is met.

Problem is I can't even compile it because it says that the End If statemement is without an If statement. But unless I'm crazy they're surely is and I have all closed the previous ones.

Anyone got any ideas?

```
For Each source_month In wb_source.Range("A1:A600")
    If source_month.Value = "01/05/2022" Then
        For Each source_total_hours In source_month.Offset(50, 0)
            If source_total_hours = "TOTALE ORE" Then Exit For
            Next source_total_hours
            End If
        For Each source_hours In source_total_hours.Offset(0, 3).Resize(, 50)
                    If IsNumeric(source_hours) Then
                    hours_list.Add (source_hours)
                    End If
        Next source_hours
        For Each source_date In source_month.Offset(1, 0).Resize(, 50)
            If IsDate(source_date) Then
                date_list.Add (source_date)
            End If
        Next source_date
    End If
Next source_month
```

Comment: `If source_total_hours = "TOTALE ORE" Then Exit For` is a single line statement move the `Exit For` to a new line

Comment: As per @Warcupine plus i then get an error on `Next source_total_hours` which i think should be after the `End if` that's just after it

Comment: High time to indent your code properly.

Comment: ^^^^^[This may be useful](https://rubberduckvba.com/Indenter)

Comment: also don't think this is doing what you want it to `For Each source_total_hours In source_month.Offset(50, 0)` think you might be meaning to use a resize here?

Comment: The 1st For .. Next loop and IF .... END IF loops are wrapped around each other

Comment: You scan for "TOTALE ORE" but you don't seem to use the position of that value later?

Comment: Its always safer to use the multi line version of 'if then else endif' rather than the single line version.  If you can, I'd sugest installing the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA so that you can easily reindent your code according to a set of rules.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - one line moved, &  as per Warcupines comment, one line split into 2

```
For Each source_month In wb_source.Range("A1:A600")
    If source_month.Value = "01/05/2022" Then
        For Each source_total_hours In source_month.Offset(50, 0)
            If source_total_hours = "TOTALE ORE" Then 
               Exit For  'MOVED THIS TO A SEPARATE LINE as per Warcupine comment
            End If    ' MOVED THIS
            Next source_total_hours
        For Each source_hours In source_total_hours.Offset(0, 3).Resize(, 50)
                    If IsNumeric(source_hours) Then
                    hours_list.Add (source_hours)
                    End If
        Next source_hours
        For Each source_date In source_month.Offset(1, 0).Resize(, 50)
            If IsDate(source_date) Then
                date_list.Add (source_date)
            End If
        Next source_date
    End If
Next source_month
```